# Error: Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost'

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm running a mysql database (managed through phpmyadmin) on a lubuntu virtual machine, which itself is on a mac 10.6.
Everything was working smoothly until earlier, (and I didn't touch any part of the login code!) when I got the following error on my pages:

> Erreur : SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I don't understand where this error is coming from as I don't have a user called www-data on phpmyadmin and my files are supposed to be using the root account on the database:

```
$dbname = 'name';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '*****';
$dbhost = 'localhost';
try{
    $linkpdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbhost.';'.$dbname.', '.$dbuser.' , '.$dbpass);
    $linkpdo -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}
```

After some googling I saw that people modified their config.conf file, but I don't know how or why.

Comment: `$linkpdo = new PDO("mysql:host='".$dbhost."';dbname='".$dbname."'",$dbuser , $dbpass);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a double quoted string and the correct parameters for the connect, its easier to build using a double quoted string and `$variable` expansion.

```
    $linkpdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $linkpdo -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: thanks, that got rid of that error, although it seems another already took its place...

Comment: You had better ask another question with details of the next error

Comment: actually, it's ok, I just forgot a { further down the code which gave me the white screen of death

Answer (score 3):

The user and password are separate parameters, http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php.

So take out the concatanation here-> `.', '.$dbuser.' , '.$dbpass`.

Connection should be:

```
$linkpdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbhost.';dbname='. $dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass);
```

Comment: You might want to check that syntax Chris

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=name;host=localhost';
$user = 'root';
$password = '*****';


try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Try this code. Checkout this link for more details http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
 $linkpdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbhost.';dbname='.$dbname , $dbuser, $dbpass);
```